# android How to Change Layout on orientation change with retaining state like youtube app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, orientation, orientation-changes

How can a layout be changed with orientation change like the  youtube app does ?
It seems like a RecyclerView that changes the item layout when in landscape mode, 
how can this be done ( I believe the fragment state is retained, so it doesn't just save state with data, latest position and so and then load landscape layout files) 
 what's the best practice to do so ?

Portrait:
[image]

Landscape:
[image]

Comment: Check this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en. It explain how to use retained instance for recreating views.

Comment: Thanks @CedricFranck , it's very heplful, but still how to change the layout same as youtube app does ?

Comment: You have to create two XML. One for portrait, the other for landscape. When you change orientation from Portrait to Landscape just save all your views  datas inside retained instance then in the on create of the activity with the Landscape view you can get back theses datas and hydrate your views.

Answer (score 2):

You may add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your activity in your manifest. So changing orientation won't reload your activity.

Comment: true but it won't change the layout files,
How i got it to work, is to put all the data I already load in the saved instance state, ( this way i won't have to call network and so )
and then under layouts folder, layout-land I put same layout resources but with different views structure thus it will be loaded automatically with the landscape layout .
Maybe another way would be done using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) I will try to investigate it , and if reached a result, I will post it here